# Is there a Stack Exchange site for technical theatre lighting design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange website that focusses on technical theatre lighting design? I am aware of such Stack sites such as [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) and [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) and these are all primarily encapsulated within Technical Theatre so I thought perhaps a site dedicated to Lighting Design might exist (aside from Electrical Engineering).

If not, is it a sufficient site proposal and will there be demand?

By "Lighting Design" I am referring to the stagecraft of operating and design lighting shows on various dimmer and DMX boards.

Comment: I don't think there is. If you propose such site on A51 you need to find the users that want to commit to that proposal.

Comment: @rene I saw that a Lighting Design site was proposed a while back but never got enough backing behind it. Do you think it is acceptable to propose a site that essentially encapsulates similar concepts that other sites already focus on? (A site on Tech Theatre would include sound designing - a concept already covered by Sound Design, for example)

Comment: Probably. I mean there's almost 200 sites, I'd check around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of the currently existing SE community that is focused on theatre lighting design.

However, there is a recent [Area 51 Theater Tech proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122545/theater-tech) that I found. This one, surprisingly (since you are posting this question now) was proposed 2 days ago (Jun 25, 2019).

I do not see a big activity there, but I can totally understand that with the right set of people it can be a popular niche community: lighting design, stage management, theatre infrastructure, etc. This proposal certainly needs a lot more active supporters to succeed and go at least for a private beta.

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence! I will definitely investigate and see if I can get some of my theatre tech friends to help back it. It really could be a great niche site :)

Comment: @Aaron I would also suggest going through the Meta's of relevant communities (Sound, Video, Movies & TV,...) for suggestions, semi-advertisement, topic overlap discussion, etc.

Comment: Great ideas, thank you very much!

Comment: @Aaron, btw, this proposal would need at least 5 followers to not be automatically deleted. I guess the deadline is today, [as per this](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51)

Comment: Only one more follower is required - hopefully it makes the deadline.